# Can't install automatically signed unlisted addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have developed a Firefox extension that is unlisted because it will only be used internally amongst the family members. After submitting it to addons.mozilla.org, it passed the validation and was signed (status: Preliminary Reviewed). However, when I go to *Manage Status and Version* page and I click on my addon (.xpi), Firefox tries to install it, but refuses to with the following message:

`Firefox has prevented this site from installing unverified addon.`

Are there any other necessary steps to take in order to be able to install my newly created addon without messing around in about:config?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign into your addons.mozilla.org account that you uploaded the addon from. Then you download the xpi from the link that got email to you automatically by AMO. You then install (and distribute to your users) that downloaded XPI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, that's exactly what I did, yet I still get the error I mentioned. Just to mention, I also tried downloading the XPI and then adding it to Firefox manually via Add-ons Manager but it results in the same error. I have not tried to unpack nor modify the signed XPI in any way ... I'll also mention that the XPI contains just 4 files - manifest, popup.html, popup.js and an icon - which are files that I created, but shouldn't there also be some signature key that was added by Mozilla when signing the XPI?

Comment: What's the link to your xpi/addon I can share it with the addon review team.

Comment: I actually managed to solve it myself - in my manifest file I had a key `applications.gecko.strict_min_version: "43.0.0"`. After removing this strict_min_version property and re-uploading the addon, everything works as it should!